# Routing paste id

Tags: angular, routes

I have some array of routing

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
        { path: 'docuement/:id', component: DocumentComponent, 
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: ListNotChosenComponent,
                },
                {
                    path: 'doc/:docId',
                    component: DocumentDetailsComponent,
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

In DocumentComponent when I click first time router work and URI change to document/:id/doc/:docId and redirect to `**<router-outlet>**` but when click second time i have erorr that Cannot match any routes. URL Segment. Angular try paste path second time

```
document/id/doc/docId1/id/doc/docId2
```

Comment: And where's the question? We're not your live debuggers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@Lazar Ljubenović](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2131286/lazar-ljubenovi%C4%87) said it's hard to help if there's no question, so please try to be more precise next time you ask something.

That said, I do have an idea from where it might come:

You probably generate a link with the `routerLink` directive and you must be using a relative path. Instead of that, try to use an absolute path like the following:
`[routerLink]="['/document', 'id', 'doc', yourDocumentIdHere]"`.

Comment: I have [routerLink]="[this._router.url + '/doc/', document.DocumentGuid] where this_router.url = '/document/id

Comment: you shouldn't have `this` into the view. It should be: `[routerLink]="[_router.url, 'doc', document.DocumentGuid]`

Comment: Ok I change to _router.url but still  'doc', document.DocumentGuid repeats itself as many times as many clicks

Comment: Do you have an error into the console? If not I can't help you without further info.

Comment: I have error into the console
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'patientDocument/3be53087-4fe5-4161-ae06-4adb97b4b94a/doc/c260bee8-7cdd-4ba5-b970-b56523a56cbe/doc/762bfb79-d77e-4337-b85c-cbaa6fe9bc5f'

Comment: Well, it says it all. You do not have any route matching the one you want. Update your post wit: 1) some more relevant code, 2) proper errors, 3) a minimal way to reproduce (stackblitz, plunkr) if possible.

Comment: Maxime I know that I have any matching route beause doc/id is append second time when click 2 times, append 3 times when i click 3 times

Comment: Maxime thanks a lot for help a tip that is relative path, i have bug because i don't use '/' at the begining